# Why is there a space at the end of even though I don't have padding in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile

I don't understand why when I scroll to the bottom of the page, there is an extra space even though I don't have padding.
Hope to receive help from everyone. Thank you

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/save-money.png',
                  height: 80,
                  width: 80,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                const Text(
                  'Sổ Thu Chi MISA',
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 16),
                )
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
            Column(),
            Column(),
            Column(),
```

The Columns in the code are just examples. The problem here is why there is an extra space at the bottom of the page like in my photo below.

[image "problem like this"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7VBZ.png)

[image "I need it like this"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVPOg.png)

Comment: Please share code of this screen

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet instead of code-image

Comment: When u want to ask question please ask it completely

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @rasityilmaz Sorry, I have added sample code to the article

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh I have added sample code to the article

Comment: It might be comming from `const SizedBox(height: 15),`

Comment: First of all, there is no problem with your code.

The widgets in the SingleChildScrollView take up as much space as they should.

If you do not want the bottom of the screen to be empty and you want my widgets to fill the entire screen, add mainAxisAlignment.center to the Column under the singleChildScrollView.

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh I think no because at the bottom of my page I don't add sizebox so it's not the cause

Comment: @rasityilmaz I tried doing as you said but it only decreased a little, 
it still not close to the edge. I want my widget to be on the bottom margin of the page

Comment: You can use mainAxisAlignment.spaceAround but ı don't suggest that 
In this way, you will have a view that does not fill the screen but can fill another screen or not fit at all, so what you want is actually a complete mistake.

Comment: Can you share a  dartpad link with gist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your unexpected space come from this line `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`, it means scrollable height equal to screen height. When your content is not long enough, as you can see extra space. Or if your content longer than user screen height, you got an overflow.

If you really want footer close to bottom edge. My idea is put they in column with a SizedBox between. First, that SizedBox has not height. After first frame drawed, you can get their height and re-calculate SizedBox height so that your footer close to bottom edge.

Here is my code example. At production environment, user can resize their screen like split apps or show/hide soft keyboard, you need to care them and edit my example. But this idea still work fine.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final contentKey = GlobalKey();
  final footerKey = GlobalKey();
  double space = 0;
  double? maxHeight;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      final contentBox = contentKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
      final footerBox = footerKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;

      if (contentBox != null && footerBox != null && maxHeight != null) {
        final contentHeight = contentBox.size.height;
        final footerHeight = footerBox.size.height;

        final expectedSpace = maxHeight! - contentHeight - footerHeight;
        if (expectedSpace != space) {
          setState(() {
            if (expectedSpace > 0) {
              space = expectedSpace;
            } else {
              space = 0;
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (ctx, cts) {
        maxHeight = cts.maxHeight;

        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                key: contentKey,
                height: 500,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: space),
              Container(
                key: footerKey,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ohh. Thank you so much. Based on your idea I removed MediaQuery then the problem was solved